# Node-js -- Download and store file - Binary - Archieve corrupt

Tags: node.js, binary, dropbox-api, node-webkit, fs

I'm using the Node.js Dropbox API to read a file, and then store it (on windows).

Its a renamed .zip file (Node Webkit package => .nw )

my code:

The {responseType: "b"} stands for binary.

```
client.readFile("package.nw", {responseType: "b"}, function(error, data) {
          if (error) {
            return showError(error);  // Something went wrong.
            throw new Error(error);
          }
            toastr.info("Storing update..");
            console.log(data);
            fs.writeFile("package.nw", data, 'binary', function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    return showError(error);
                }

                toastr.info("Update complete!");
            });
        });
```

When I try to open the package, its corrupted.

How can I save it propperly?
Thanks in advance, Jeroen

Comment: I think you'd be better off with `{responseType: "buffer"}`, and then remove your `'binary'` argument from `writeFile`. Haven't use this module, but that is what it looks like in my quick check.

Comment: the original file size is 541kb (package.nw as uploaded). when i use "buffer", the file size turns to 1008kb, and the archive is still corrupt..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

```
client.readFile("package.nw", {binary : true}, function(error, data) {
          if (error) {
            return showError(error);  // Something went wrong.
            throw new Error(error);
          }
            toastr.info("Storing update..");
            console.log(data);
            fs.writeFile("package.nw", data, 'binary', function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    return showError(error);
                }

                toastr.info("Update complete!");
            });
        });
```

had to use {binary : true} to get it working!
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/js#Dropbox.Client.readFile